# JsonApi method calls

Tags: rest, domain-driven-design, json-api

How may I include, using JsonApi, links to methods in my Rest API?, for example I have something like this:

```
POST api/v1/customer/1/deactivate
POST api/v1/customer/1/activate
```

To activate and deactivate a customer correspondingly. How they should be included (or not) in my data object? The [specification](http://jsonapi.org/format/#document-top-level) does not include something like "methods" section for the data object.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Updating based on your change and based on guillaume31's answer.

If it is truly an update to a resource then you should issue a PATCH to:
    api/v1/customer/1

And with a jsonapi compliant body to update the resource:

```
{
  "data": {
    "type": "customer",
    "id": "1",
    "attributes": {
        "status": "deactivated"
    }
  }
}
```

If the intent is to truly remove the resource then a delete may be more appropriate. Based on your description the PATCH may be the best path since the resource is still present and may be restored based on other calls

Comment: I updated my question to clarify a bit more, do you think your solution can apply to this case?

Comment: I think this is the right way to do it using JsonApi

Answer (score 1):

> `POST api/v1/customer/1/deactivate`
>
> `POST api/v1/customer/1/activate`

This is not RESTful. But the "active" state of a customer can be seen as a resource! So the simplest solution is the following:

```
PUT api/v1/customer/1/active      # Activates customer 1
DELETE api/v1/customer/1/active    # Deactivates customer 1
```

The PATCH solution described by @guillaume31 is also a valid approach, but [implementing RESTful PATCH correctly](http://williamdurand.fr/2014/02/14/please-do-not-patch-like-an-idiot/) requires that the *change* is described with operation, data pointer and new value (see also the [JSON Patch RFC](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6902)). That's probably overkill for this simple scenario.

Comment: +1 for the RESTful solution. That was more or less what I was referring to in my answer. I would probably rather go with distinct `/prospect/1`, `/customer/1` or `/customers/inactive/1` resources and associated POST/DELETE verbs to reflect different states though.

Answer (score 0):

By including "deactivate" as part of the URI, you're kind of making deactivate a resource, which seems incorrect. This IMO isn't [REST level 1](http://martinfowler.com/articles/richardsonMaturityModel.html) compliant.

As I understand it, activating/deactivating a customer amounts to updating a resource. JsonApi recommends sending a PATCH request to modify a resource : http://jsonapi.org/format/#crud-updating

However, it would perhaps be more faithful to REST to model activation as a POST or a PUT and deactivation as a DELETE. You would benefit from PUT and DELETE's [idempotency](http://restcookbook.com/HTTP%20Methods/idempotency/) -- activating or deactivating a customer twice in a row should probably leave it in the same state. But it also depends on your domain and what consequences these actions have.

In the REST frameworks I know, verbs are not included in links out of the box. I doesn't seem to be the case with JSON API [either](http://jsonapi.org/format/#document-links).

Comment: Yes, it is not a RESTFUL point of view. I like the idea to use Post/Put and Delete to activate and deactivate.